# Как удалить из объекта все что равно 0?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть объек примерно такой:

```
[
   {
      "created_at" : "2021-07-16 03:31:29",
      "updated_at" : "2021-07-16 03:31:29",
      "token_id" : "32ae6bba4748067c7ff26a60b3ebc825d1f18fd67d1d15ffa2c1d198c4f4eca736fd6d8b45956259",
      "state" : "0"
   },
   {
      "created_at" : "2021-07-19 03:02:19",
      "updated_at" : "2021-07-19 03:02:19",
      "token_id" : "2a01f8956acd98fe980037aa1a1ae700f0ca0d557b4cebc8b2ad06c8c9cc9f81c77156ce9c6f342b",
      "state" : "0"
   },
   {
      "created_at" : "2021-07-19 03:02:59",
      "updated_at" : "2021-07-19 03:02:59",
      "token_id" : "a43a119602ddacb5cad01625715f162dbe852da1af516db3ce5f1d52ea08482cd645157550f7a96b",
      "state" : "0"
   },
   {
      "created_at" : "2021-07-19 03:03:08",
      "updated_at" : "2021-07-19 03:03:08",
      "token_id" : "b52a73bd5552ab9c7982db30ab1d8bfcc80ee64f58275fd2f0d56cacbf204f25654ad713516ba69b",
      "state" : "1"
   },
]
```

Как удалить все где state равен 0? Через JS.

upd. Обновил пример кода. Нужно убрать все объекты где state: 0

Comment: `arr = arr.filter(({ state }) => state != 0);` это самый простой вариант. Если хочется с приведением значения к числовому, то `arr = arr.filter(({ state }) => state && (+state !== 0));` - тут первая проверка исключает возможное ложное срабатывание второй проверки (со значением `null`, которое при типкасте к `number` тоже даст `0`). Еще через типкаст к `string` можно, `String(state) === '0'`, но это _почти что_ аналог первого варианта.

Comment: Вариант c типкастом к строке и случай с `null` я неправильно написал: при типкасте к числу тут подойдет и простое условие `+state !== 0` (т.к. учитывать `null` имело бы смысл при задаче "оставить только с `0`", а тут надо наоборот убрать нулевые, значит скорее всего нужно любое falsy значение понимать как нулевое, и отсутствие свойства соотв.)... Ну а в выражении через типкаст к строке, у меня банально опечатка, опять же из-за обратной логики (должно быть `String(state) !== '0'`).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [{
    "created_at": "2021-07-16 03:31:29",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-16 03:31:29",
    "token_id": "32ae6bba4748067c7ff26a60b3ebc825d1f18fd67d1d15ffa2c1d198c4f4eca736fd6d8b45956259",
    "state": "0"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2021-07-19 03:02:19",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-19 03:02:19",
    "token_id": "2a01f8956acd98fe980037aa1a1ae700f0ca0d557b4cebc8b2ad06c8c9cc9f81c77156ce9c6f342b",
    "state": "0"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2021-07-19 03:02:59",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-19 03:02:59",
    "token_id": "a43a119602ddacb5cad01625715f162dbe852da1af516db3ce5f1d52ea08482cd645157550f7a96b",
    "state": "0"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2021-07-19 03:03:08",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-19 03:03:08",
    "token_id": "b52a73bd5552ab9c7982db30ab1d8bfcc80ee64f58275fd2f0d56cacbf204f25654ad713516ba69b",
    "state": "1"
  },
];


for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (a[i].state !== `0`) continue;
  a.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(a);
```